# In Angular 2 in .ts file showing underline below class name

Tags: typescript, angular

I am beginner and writing first app in electron+angular 2.In `.ts` in classname there is underline showing sublime, and if I run with that showing module app not found. Here is a snapshot.[image: here in classname there is a underline]

here is the project directory

[image]

Comment: When you place the mouse over the class name `ContactComponent` it should show a tooltip with more information about the cause.

Comment: no..its not showing

Comment: let  it show. When you build it, what happens ?

Comment: BTW, the IDE looks like alm.tools ? Is that correct ? Anyways, build the code to see the error.

Comment: when I buld it with webpack...it bulds...but after doing npm start it says module app(root component) not found.

Comment: no..its sublime text

Comment: Try to rename your component, to just "Contact", is the underline still on? If it is then look into your tsConfig.json file, if you have the "experimentalDecorators" option set to true?

Comment: can you give a screnshot of your project directory

Comment: @AngJobs ..yes it still reamain and option is true..

Comment: @pdfarhad..I uploaded directory

Comment: your app.ts , can you show your app.ts code and error log with a screenshot. Btw did you rename the component ?

Comment: Could you load the project in Visual Code and see if the underline is still on?